# Trying to minus 2 values together results in them adding instead, also all operators exept addition do not function

Tags: c#, operators, converters

For some reason when I test the code the minus if statement adds the two values togehther instead of minusing them, along with that the other if statements for times and subtraction return the error message

System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

The first if statement for addition works fine despite this

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Calculation()
    {
        decimal answer;

        if (savedOperator == "+")
        {
            answer = savedNumber + Convert.ToDecimal(txtBox.Text);
            txtBox.Text = answer.ToString();
            savedOperator = "";
        }

        if (savedOperator == "-")
        {
            answer = savedNumber - Convert.ToDecimal(txtBox.Text);
            txtBox.Text = answer.ToString();
            savedOperator = "";
        }

        if (savedOperator == "*")
        {
            answer = savedNumber * Convert.ToDecimal(txtBox.Text);
            txtBox.Text = answer.ToString();
            savedOperator = "";
        }

        if (savedOperator == "/")
        {
            answer = savedNumber / Convert.ToDecimal(txtBox.Text);
            txtBox.Text = answer.ToString();
            savedOperator = "";
        }

    }

    private void SaveNumber()
    {
        savedNumber = System.Convert.ToDecimal(txtBox.Text);

        txtUpperBox.Text = savedNumber.ToString();
    }

    // numbers

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + "1";
    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + "2";
    }

    private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + "3";
    }

    private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + "4";
    }

    private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + "5";
    }

    private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + "6";
    }

    private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + "7";
    }

    private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + "8";
    }

    private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + "9";
    }

    private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text + "0";
    }

    // operators

    private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveNumber();
        txtBox.Clear();
        savedOperator = "+";
        txtBox.Text = "+";
    }

    private void btnMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveNumber();
        txtBox.Clear();
        savedOperator = "-";
        txtBox.Text = "-";
    }

    private void btnTimes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveNumber();
        txtBox.Clear();
        savedOperator = "*";
        txtBox.Text = "*";
    }

    private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveNumber();
        txtBox.Clear();
        savedOperator = "/";
        txtBox.Text = "/";
    }

    private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Calculation();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is a **great** opportunity to learn how to debug code using the **[free, awesome, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any obvious problems in your math logic.

I tested it in https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uo2EHM and it works fine.  The issue could be in the inputs you are getting or in conversion.

You can either set breakpoints at various points in your code to see what the values are or print out the values to another "debug" text box.

Some potential issues I see are in conversion between number and string.  Sometimes, it may not give you the results you expect.

Also, you might want to use a `switch` statement instead of multiple `if` statements but that is not a bug you are seeing.

Could the issue be with the value of the TextBox before the calculations are performed?  If you have "8--3" it would be the same as 8 - (-3).  Try your code with different text boxes for the numbers and the operators to see if the problem occurs.